# React useState() -- State value is always empty in useCallback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm creating a treeview checkbox where oncheck I'm creating an array of the selected values and setting it my state. Now on debounce call I need these values to set some data in the call. But in the debounce function call I get the state array as empty always. Even though I saw that the values are inside the state still I'm facing empty values in the function.

This is the code for taking Checkbox value in array

```js
 const getCheckedValues = (e) => {

        if (e.target.checked) {
            tableData.filter(function (obj) {
                if (obj['id'] === Number(e.target.id)) {
                    updatedList = [...inputArr, { // and adding this new object
                        id: obj['id'],
                        schemaName: obj['schemaName'],
                        tableName: obj['tableName'],
                        keys: obj['keys']
                    }
                    ];
                    setInputArr(updatedList);
                    console.log(inputArr)
                }
            })
            }
```

This is where I want to use that state value but array is empty all the time.

```js
const debounceOnChangeScript = React.useCallback(debounce(onChangeScript, 1000), []);

function onChangeScript(value, id) {

        console.log('Inside onChangeScript')
        console.log(inputArr)
        
      console.log(inputArrData);
        inputArr.filter(element => { console.log(element)})
        }
```

I'm still new react and trying understand this state concept and tried every possible solution from the internet but still facing this issue.
Please help me out where exactly I'm making any mistake or missing something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The React useCallback Hook returns a memoized callback function.

here `debounceOnChangeScript` will be created only once when the component first mounts so when `inputArr` is an empty array.
 that's why it will always be `[]` when you try to get its value from inside `debounceOnChangeScript`.
 what you want here, is to recreate the function each time `inputArr` is updated to always have access to its newest value.
 to do so, you just have to put `inputArr` in the dependency array of the `useCallback` hook:

```js
const debounceOnChangeScript = React.useCallback(debounce(onChangeScript, 1000), [inputArr]);
```

learn more about [useCallback](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback).